# Android SDK VERSION_CODES.S not found even I have installed SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-pendingintent, onesignal, android-sdk-manager

I hava faced issue when imported from Android 11 to 13. When receive notification with OneSignal I get crash.. and the message is **Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.**

So I checked PendingIntent class. and this is my code

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationDetails.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

then I read how to solve it.

the suggest is..

```
 if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.S) {
  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    notificationDetails.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        }else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    notificationDetails.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```

Then my problem is when I use VERSION_CODES.S .the level S is not found.. even tough I have installed SDK 31 and setup compilesdk 33. and targetSdkVersion 31.

Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, which I have fixed by using this method. Try to import the correct package.

```
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
  ...
}
```

And I have installed only `Android 13.0 (Tiramisu)` and `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` version are

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        }
   ...
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: import android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
is not found

Comment: Your targetSdkVersion is 31; it can be less than the compileSdkVersion, but try to make it similar to the compileSdkVersion, which is 33 in your case.